# FormSet Not Saving Image or validating

Tags: django

When I enter info into my formset, the images gets erased and I'm not able to advance to the next page. No errors appear on the page. Essentially, the form data isn't passing "is_valid". I'm pretty certain that there is something wrong in my view.py.

Models.py

```
class Testimonial(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    image = VersatileImageField('image_testimonial', upload_to=upload_location, validators=[file_size], null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username
```

forms.py

```
class TestimonialForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Testimonial
        fields = ('image', 'message', 'name', 'city', 'state',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/") 
def testimonials(request):

TestimonialFormSet = modelformset_factory(Testimonial, form=TestimonialForm, extra=3)

if request.method == 'POST':

    formset = TestimonialFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:             #for instance in instances.cleaned_data:
            instance.author = request.user
            fix_orientation(instance.image)
            instance.save()

        return redirect('/accounts/profile/')

    else:                        
        args = {'formset': formset}
        return render(request, 'accounts/page6.html', args)
else:

    formset = TestimonialFormSet(queryset=Testimonial.objects.filter(author=request.user))

return render(request, 'accounts/page6.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Are you showing `formset.errors` in the template? What does it display?

Comment: Ah, no. I'm displaying form.errors. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented formset.errors on my page as well as formset.non_form_errors. On form submission, the following error is being displayed: [{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}, {}]. I'm not sure what this is about as id isn't part of the model, but I'll start looking into it. Thanks for the lead on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to 
a) include {{formset.errors}} in my template to render the error that was preventing submission

b) include  {{ form.id }} in the template even though id isn't part of my model. This seems to be an odd quirk of formset, but alas, I can now submit the form.

Shoutout to Daniel Roseman for helping me find the answer!